# Como importar o pacote "javax.measure" sem IDE?

Tags: java-8, importação

Estou tentando importar, em Java 8 e sem usar IDE, o pacote `javax.measure` com o seguinte código:

```
import javax.measure;

public class Measure {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Importou!");
    }
}
```

O problema é que quando eu tento compilar com o `javac`, o seguinte erro é gerado:

```
Measure.java:1: error: package javax does not exist
import javax.measure;
```

Pesquisando na internet, eu só encontrei páginas sobre como importar o `javax` através do Eclipse. Eu gostaria de saber como faço isso sem usar a IDE.

Comment: E qual gerenciador de pacotes está usando "stand alone" (sem IDE)? Maven ou gradle? Segue aqui como instalar usando diferentes gerenciadores de pacotes: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.measure/unit-api/2.1.2 ... só pra constar, javax não é um pacote com tudo do "javax", é um namespace, provavelmente focado em "extensões" (questão antiga, decisões antigas também), diversos pacotes de terceiros podem ser usando nisso. Até o Tomcat (alguns do tomcat já mudaram de namespace) e o Apache tem APIs que usam esse namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro vamos falar de um problema na sua linha de import. Conforme o [comentário do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510200/como-importar-o-pacote-javax-sem-ide/510202#comment936729_510200) `javax` é um *namespace* genérico para extensões, alguns pacotes dentro do `javax` fazem parte da distribuição Java SE e outros não. O `javax.measure` em especial não faz parte da distribuição padrão do Java.

Além disso, em Java você nunca importa um pacote como `javax.measure` diretamente.

Você pode importar uma classe específica do pacote, por exemplo:

```
import javax.measure.Dimension;
```

Ou você pode importar todas as classes do pacote (mas não recursivamente dentro de subpacotes):

```
import javax.measure.*;
```

Sobre a sua pergunta, a [JSR-363](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=363) é a especificação da *Units of Measurement API* (pacote `javax.measure`). Há também a mais atual [JSR-385](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=385) que específica a versão 2.0 dessa API. Para compilar e rodar sua aplicação fora do IDE você vai precisar fazer o download não só da API, mas também da implementação de referência ou de uma das [implementações compatíveis](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/implementations/jsr363/index.html). Uma vez que você tenha todos os artefatos deve [incluí-los no *class path*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Geralmente um sistema de *build* com suporte a controle declarativo de dependências como o [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) ou o [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) é usado para fazer esse tipo de coisa. Com essas ferramentas você pode declarar a implementação que você deseja e o sistema fará o download e a inclusão de todos os artefatos necessários no *class path*.

Por exemplo, com o Maven você pode adicionar a seguinte dependência ao pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>tech.units</groupId>
  <artifactId>indriya</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

E então rodar o seguinte comando para compilar o seu projeto:

```
mvn compile
```

Com isso o Maven fará o download da [Indriya](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya), implementação de referência da JSR-385. O Maven também fará download de todas as dependências transitivas, incluindo a unit-api-2.1.2.jar (versão mais atual da API) linkada pelo Guilherme.

Alternativamente, ao menos para fins de estudo, nada te impede de fazer o download dos jars necessários e todas as suas dependências manualmente. Veja que se o jar A que você precisa depende de um jar B que por sua vez depende de C e D você precisará de A, B, C e D no *class path*. Em um projeto real o controle manual de dependências logo se torna tedioso e eu certamente recomendaria o uso de uma ferramenta de *build*.

Vamos assumir, por exemplo, que você fez o download do jar da versão desejada da API, de um implementação compatível como o [uom-se](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se) e de todas as dependências da implementação. Esses artefatos foram salvos em uma pasta `lib` junto ao seu código:

```
lib/
    unit-api-1.0.jar
    uom-lib-common-1.0.3.jar
    uom-se-1.0.10.jar
Measure.java
```

Você pode compilar a classe `Measure` com:

```
javac -cp "lib/*" Measure.java
```

E rodar a aplicação com:

```
java -cp "lib/*" Measure
```

PS: Nesse caso trivial somente o jar da API é necessário para a etapa de compilação, os demais artefatos são necessários apenas em tempo de execução. Na teoria isso faz com que seja possível trocar a implementação de determinads API sem ter que recompilar ou mexer na aplicação. Na prática porém, nem sempre isso funciona como deveria. Pequenas diferenças de implementação podem causar problemas em tempo de execução. Quem já teve que trocar a implementação do JPA ou JAX-RS ou JAXB em um projeto sabe bem do que eu estou falando. O spec líder da JSR-385 e autor da Indriya por exemplo disponibiliza classes extras na implementação e recomenda o seu uso direto (veja: https://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/indriya/)